# Vertical menu strange behaviour with Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui, masonry

I am trying to use a masonry grid inside a semantic container which is in a column. I have created a simple fiddle  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cu33v8rk/11/). Since it is quite a lot, I will not post everything, just what I think causes the problem:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui top attached buttons padded grid">
  <div data-bind="click: expander" class="ui column button groupheader center aligned">
    <i class="caret down icon"></i>
    <span> Group 1 </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-responsive expander hidden">
  <table class="ui compact celled unstackable table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="seven wide">Key</th>
        <th class="seven wide right aligned">Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    ...
</div>
```

**Knockoutjs**

```
self.expander = function(group, event){
  var nextExpander = $(event.currentTarget).parent().next('.expander');
  if (nextExpander.is(':visible')){
    nextExpander.transition({
      animation: 'slide down',
      duration: 400,
      onHide: function () {
        $('#masonry-grid').masonry('layout');        
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    nextExpander.transition('slide down', 400);
    $('#masonry-grid').masonry();
  }
}
```

Once a user clicks on a Group, it will toggle visible or invisible with the semantic transition 'slide down'. The problem is once the content turns invisible by the slide down animation I tell in the onComplete Handler masonry to layout again. After the animation of both, semanticss 'slide down' and masonrys 'layout' are finished the menu is no longer visible. It somehow moved away and also changed it's sizes.

In order for the problem to occur the grid layout needs a width of at least 1350px, else it works as wished.
Additionally if the animation of masonrys 'layout' is disabled it works as wished.
And if masonrys 'layout' does not have to animate changes to the Groups the problem also does not occur (just click on the last Group and you will see).

Does someone has an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, I was only able to replicate the particular bug in Chrome. Try setting the z-index of the menu item to auto (currently set to 101 by semantic.min.css).

```
.ui.menu.fixed {
    z-index: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much taking your time debugging it. This solved it!